# Mamp Pro and WordPress _ ( score function )

Tags: wordpress, mamp, mamp-pro

I had an issue using the function _('string') doesn't matter the context or if it is used as parameter for another function or called normally.

Every time I use the function I get the page broken, no error no info. Nothing. Just stop there where rendering at the moment.

es.

```
$data->content = sprintf(
    esc_html__('Proudly by %s - Theme Name: %s', 'textdomain'),
    '<a href="https://url">' . _('SiteName') . '</a>',
    '<a href="http://url">' . _('ThemeName') . '</a>'
);
```

Comment: Any useful information in mamp's error log?

Comment: No errors, the browser engine just stop at the line where the function is used. I updated the question with an example.

Comment: Does the same happen when using gettext() instead of _()?

Comment: No, also, if I create the function since the wp one is pluggable, the issue doesn't appear. I use namespaces by the way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use translation function of WordPress, you need two underscore not one :

```
__('string');
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I know the __ function, my question was not for translating string but for a function issue.